# Is there a way by which I can have Stack Overflow results rank higher for me, than other results on Google?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, google, search-engine

I think the quality of Stack Overflow questions and answers is, in general, better than the web results for the same queries returned by search engines. So, personally I'd always like to see if Stack Overflow (or any Stack Exchange site for that matter) has something related to what I'm looking for on Google.

But, I don't want to just search on Stack Exchange sites, so I still want to search on Google first, it's just that I want to see Stack results on first page, even if Google doesn't think they are more appropriate. May be something like [Google Subscribed links](http://www.google.com/coop/docs/guide_subscribed_links.html)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This [has been asked on the Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-can-i-make-google-prioritize-stackoverflow-results). Some suggestions from there:

- Add `stackoverflow` to your search query
- [A custom search that emphasizes Stack Overflow results](http://www.google.com/cse/home?cx=001706605492879182808:8b-lak46mtw)

Another possibility would be to create a browser extension that detects Google searches, does a Stack Overflow-only search in the background, and injects the results in the Google page. I don't think anyone has written that yet.

Comment: Actually I myself append "stack" to my search query, which I think is better than appending "stackoverflow" as it'll include other Stack sites as well, and also it's (much) shorter. Custom Search IMO isn't a good solution. 
The extension approach sounds interesting! :)

Comment: couldn't vote up your answer as I'm new here, and don't have enough reputation...but Thanks for it :)

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome (possibly other browsers as well) grab the [Personal Block List](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef) extension.  You can block all the BS sites that clone SO content or that try to FYF with SEO.

Answer (score 1):

Simply having a lot of replies, positive criticism and better still on a wider range of time makes it even higher in the SE index.